# android app invoking google map with car,public,walking controls

Tags: android, google-maps

Im having problems porting some functions of Iphone application to Android.
Basically iphone google map app that is invoked from this app looks like this

[image]

I have tried to copy similar behaviour using this pseudo code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+LAT_POSITION+","+LONG_POSITION+"&daddr="+Lat+","+Lon + "&dirflg=w"));
startActivity(intent);
```

what it does it brings the android map app in this form

[image]

so then when i click show map i get

[image]

and then when i press back twice i get this

[image]

my questions are.

How I can get the (car,public,walk) controls overlay the map? just like in iphone app - on one screen (other elements too if possible)

additional question..
How I can enable showing map by default? (instead of textual directions, this is happening in android 2.2 - I have checked on samsung galaxy with froyo) , In 4.0 (emulator) the map is showing by default but still there are no overlay controls (car,public,walk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setComponent` to explicitly tell the Maps app to use `com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity` to resolve the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + LAT_POSITION + "," + LONG_POSITION +
    "&daddr=" + lat + "," + lon + "&dirflg=w"));
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.apps.maps", 
    "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

You should get the directions overlay but I'm not sure it will draw the route until the user hits "Go".

Of course this is "non API" and assumes that Maps is installed on the device and that Google will not change the internal packgage or class name for `MapsActivity`.

Comment: There is a ""&dirflg=w" flag on url, do we still need hit "go" button ?